# how to access members of processed futures in distributed dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to access the members of a class that I initialized in the cluster

```
B = client.submit(KDTree, A)
```

where `A` is some list of numbers already in the cluster and `KDTree` is [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)
 now i want to call `query_ball_point` method of the kdtree i made on a further list, but how do i do that in the cluster? best i managed to figure out is to use this as a function to map

```
lambda x:B.result().query_ball_point(x, 5)
```

but that cant be right, can it?
maybe the answer to this is in the docs but i can't seem to google the right thing, what is this action called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass futures into other submit calls

```
A_future = client.submit(KDTree, A)

def func(kd_tree, x):
    return kd_tree.query_ball_point(x, 5)

x = client.submit(func, A_future, x)  # or use map here or whatnot
```